# shutil.rmtree() clarification

Tags: python, python-2.7, shutil

I have read the documentation for this function, however, I dont think I understand it properly. If anyone can tell me what I'm missing, or if I am correct, it would be a great help. Here is my understanding:

using the `shutil.rmtree(path)` function, it will delete only the directory specified, not the entire path. IE:

`shutil.rmtree('user/tester/noob')`

using this, it would only delete the 'noob' directory correct? not the complete path?

Comment: What do you mean by "not the complete path"?  What would happen if it would "delete the complete path"?

Comment: the complete path as in `'user/tester/noob'`. IE delete the user directory containing tester and noob.

Comment: @IT Ninja: what was the result when you tested?  -Step 1

Comment: it works exactly like `rm -rf /dir1/dir2/dir3`, it only deletes dir3 and everything under it

Answer (score 97, accepted):

If noob is a directory, the `shutil.rmtree()` function will delete `noob` and all files and subdirectories below it.  That is, `noob` is the root of the tree to be removed.

Answer (score 36):

This will definitely only delete the last directory in the specified path.
Just try it out:

```
mkdir -p foo/bar
python
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('foo/bar')
```

...will only remove `'bar'`.

Answer (score 24):

There is some misunderstanding here.

Imagine a tree like this:

```
 - user
   - tester
     - noob
   - developer
     - guru
```

If you want to delete `user`, just do `shutil.rmtree('user')`. This will also delete `user/tester` and `user/tester/noob` as they are inside `user`. However, it will also delete `user/developer` and `user/developer/guru`, as they are also inside `user`.

If `rmtree('user/tester/noob')` would delete `user` and `tester`, how do you mean `user/developer` would exist if `user` is gone?

---

Or do you mean something like http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.removedirs ?

It tries to remove the parent of each removed directory until it fails because the directory is not empty. So in my example tree, `os.removedirs('user/tester/noob')` would remove first `noob`, then it would try to remove `tester`, which is ok because it's empty, but it would stop at `user` and leave it alone, because it contains `developer`, which we do not want to delete.

Answer (score 3):

```
**For Force deletion using rmtree command in Python:**

[user@severname DFI]$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Aug  4 2017, 17:56:03)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import shutil
>>> shutil.rmtree('user/tester/noob')



But what if the file is not existing, it will throw below error:


>>> shutil.rmtree('user/tester/noob')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 239, in rmtree
    onerror(os.listdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 237, in rmtree
    names = os.listdir(path)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'user/tester/noob'
>>>

**To fix this, use "ignore_errors=True" as below, this will delete the folder at the given if found or do nothing if not found**


>>> shutil.rmtree('user/tester/noob', ignore_errors=True)
>>>

Hope this helps people who are looking for force  folder deletion using rmtree.
```